# Dynamic form with parent child combos

Tags: angularjs

I am very new to AngularJS and after watching some pluralsight videos I decided to build a simple web page using it.

The page should initially load with one select box which is populated by an ajax request (this contains all of the data).  Then, based on the value selected, a new select element may need to be created containing the child data.  This will continue to happen until an option is selected that has no child ids.  The format of data I get back from the api is as follows.

```
[ { "ChildIds" : [  ],
    "Id" : "1",
    "Name" : "Top Level",
    "ParentId" : null
  },
  { "ChildIds" : [ "51" ],
    "Id" : "22",
    "Name" : "LevelA - 1",
    "ParentId" : "1"
  },
  { "ChildIds" : [ "38",
        "26"
      ],
    "Id" : "24",
    "Name" : "LevelA - 2",
    "ParentId" : "1"
  },
  { "ChildIds" : [  ],
    "Id" : "38",
    "Name" : "LevelB - 1",
    "ParentId" : "24"
  },
  { "ChildIds" : [  ],
    "Id" : "26",
    "Name" : "LevelB - 2",
    "ParentId" : "24"
  },
  { "ChildIds" : [  ],
    "Id" : "51",
    "Name" : "LevelB - 3",
    "ParentId" : "22"
  },
  { "ChildIds" : [ "43",
        "21"
      ],
    "Id" : "36",
    "Name" : "LevelC - 1",
    "ParentId" : "26"
  },
  { "ChildIds" : [  ],
    "Id" : "43",
    "Name" : "LevelD - 1",
    "ParentId" : "36"
  },
  { "ChildIds" : [  ],
    "Id" : "21",
    "Name" : "LevelD -2",
    "ParentId" : "36"
  }
]
```

I have managed to get this working by using hard coded select elements but want to make this dynamic.

**Html**

```
<div class="container">
        <div ng-controller="organisationalUnitCtrl">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="root" ng-options="ou.Name for ou in ous | filter:{ParentId:'!'}">
                <option value="">-- choose organisation unit --</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="child" ng-options="ou.Name for ou in ous | filter:{ParentId:root.Id}">
                <option value="">-- choose organisation unit --</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="child2" ng-options="ou.Name for ou in ous | filter:{ParentId:child.Id}">
                <option value="">-- choose organisation unit --</option>
            </select>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="child3" ng-options="ou.Name for ou in ous | filter:{ParentId:child2.Id}">
                <option value="">-- choose organisation unit --</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
bristowRiskApp.controller('organisationalUnitCtrl',
    function organisationalUnitCtrl($scope, organisationalUnitData) {
        $scope.ous = organisationalUnitData.getOrganisationalUnit();
    }
);
```

**Service**

```
bristowRiskApp.factory('organisationalUnitData', function ($http, $q) {
    return {
        getOrganisationalUnit: function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:53995/api/organisationalunit' }).
                success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).
                error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
});
```

I have read that you should not manipulate the DOM in the controller.  So, I am guessing that I should create a directive for my select element that listens for onChange events and creates the new select element?  How do I do this?  Are there any examples out there that I could learn from?

One other issue I face with my hard coded example is that changing a value in a select only ripples to the next combo.  For example, if values were selected in all four select boxes, changing a value in the second one would correctly reset the third box but the fourth will still contain the selected option.  I thought the change would be rippled all the way down.

Thanks

Steven

Comment: Yeah you need a directive for that.  I've actually written a lazily loaded tree before like that - but it's property of my company since I did it on their dime so I can't just provide the source.  If you read about directives and come back with specific questions I can help.  Although maybe not the most efficient way you will probably need to request the `$compile` service and use that in your `link` function.  I learned directives and angular via google (and much SO), trial and error.  I don't know of a great place to learn specifically about directives.

Comment: Learn about: directives, isolate scopes, `=`, `&`, `@` for communicating inside isolate scopes, `$compile` service, `angular.element` for creating the recursive elements, using the `link` property on directives.  That might be everything you need.  Another word of advice: to make this reusable have the directive accept `&`  for what to do for clicking and where to get the text to display (as oppose to hard-coding a `.text` property accessor).

Comment: Thanks Jared.  I haven't had that much time to work on it lately but have researched isolate scopes and the methods of communicating with my directive.

I've managed to at least create the combo using a directive and passing in the necessary parameters.  The part that I am just not getting is where to capture the change in the combo.  I have created an element.on method that triggers as it is supposed to.  However, I don't seem to have access to the data that I require.  I have created a fiddle based on what I have done so far.  Right direction?

http://jsfiddle.net/stevendwebster/E5ss4/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if/why this doesn't work and I'll fix it accordingly.  I think the key fact is in the options repeater you weren't using the syntax to specify the ID of the option - you were just doing its label.

http://jsfiddle.net/KVdqb/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="bristowRiskApp" ng-controller="organisationalUnitCtrl">
    $scope.selections: <pre>{{ selections | json }}</pre>
    <div ng-repeat="i in range(selections.length - 1)">
        <cascade-select data="data" parent-id="selections[i]" selected-id="selections[i + 1]"></cascade-select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var bristowRiskApp = angular.module('bristowRiskApp', []);

bristowRiskApp.controller('organisationalUnitCtrl',

function organisationalUnitCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = [ /* ... */ ];

    $scope.selections = [ null, null ];

    $scope.$watch('selections', function (value) {
        if (value[value.length - 1] !== null || value.length < 2) {
            value.push(null);
        } else {
            var index = value.indexOf(null, 1);
            if (0 < index && index < value.length - 1) {
                $scope.selections = value.slice(0, index);
            }
        }

    }, true);

    // Helper function.    
    $scope.range = function (n) {
        var result = [];

        for (var i = 0 ; i <n; i++) {
            result.push(i);
        }

        return result;
    };
});

bristowRiskApp.directive('cascadeSelect', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            parentId: '&',
            selectedId: '=',
            data: '='
        },
        template: '<select ng-show="(data | filter:byId).length > 0" ng-model="selectedId" ng-options="d.Id as d.Name for d in data | filter:byId"><option value="">-- choose organisation unit --</option></select>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.byId = function (d) {
                return d.ParentId === scope.parentId();
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jared.  That is exactly what I am looking for and I can't find any issues with it.  I'm off to study your code a little more closely and try and learn the techniques you have used.

Comment: :) Let me know if you have anything that stumps you.

Comment: Hi Jared, the "byId" function stumped me for a while but then read in the documentation that you can pass in a function as the comparator.  One thing that I did need to add was code to handle a combo changing higher up in the hierarchy.  For example, if 4 combos had values and I changed the 2nd, it would clear the third and awaut selection but the 4th would not be deleted.

Comment: I added this and it seems to have done the trick.

`var diff = $(oldvalue).not(newvalue).get();

            if (diff.length > 0) {
                var diffindex = oldvalue.indexof(diff[0]);

                if (diffindex > 0) {
                    $scope.selections = newvalue.slice(0, diffindex + 1);
                }
            }`

Now just wrangling on the best way to call a function on one controller from another. :)

Cheers

Comment: Well if you want controllers to communicate with one another you have two (I think) choices: create a shared service (remember services are singleton, though) or have something implicitly shared on the scope (maybe a third controller that is a common ancestor of the other two controllers, possibly one or the other).