# How to remove selected item not available in select tag AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on AngularJS, I have a problem as below, I have tried some solutions but they're not working, so I am posting this question here to get support from all of you:

I have two selectbox as below, when I select a parent from parent list, I will have a list of child in child list.

[image]

But, when I chose a child in child list, then change parent, as you know, we have a new child list, and chose child is not belong to new list, so we have two selected items as below.

[image]

How to remove this selected item not available.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your html with controller

Comment: the JSfiddle in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18790619/836381 answer describes how to have parent child select boxes.
I will suggest you to look into it.